Animating the Pupils of Cartoon Eyes (Flat Shaded Eyes)
Blender 4.1.1
How do I animate these pupils so they don’t show outside the whites of the eyes like in image A? Image B is what I don’t want. The eyes are flat 2D eyes made as 3D objects in regular(?) mode and not 2D Animation. They’re on a 3D model.
I tried using a Holdout but it erases everything behind it. I may not be doing it right. I only want the eyes affected. I’m fine with remaking the eyes as long as I can use them on my 3D model.
Edit:
The eyes aren't sunk into the model. I want them floating on the model. There's no eyelids. Is there a way to mask just the outsides of the eyes and nothing behind them? When the pupils go beyond the whites they don't show is what I want.


Without knowing more about your blend file, it's almost impossible to answer you. What about putting the skin above the pupil (skin closer to camera than eyes) ? Plus, that's physically what's happening (skin occluding part of the eye), even if that does not matter in itself.

The eyes aren't sunk into the model. I want them floating on the model. There's no eyelids. Is there a way to mask just the outsides of the eyes and nothing behind them? When the pupils go beyond the whites they don't show is what I want.

Edit the white circle material so your pupil is part of the material and controlled by an empty :

The Texture Coordinate node captures the position of the empty
The Multiply node makes make this position 2D
The length node calculates the distance from the empty for each point of the surface
If the distance is greater than the set pupil radius, it is white, else it is black
Each eye should have its own material to have a different empty



@ Romain Guimbal Thanks for responding. I'm sorry but I'm confused. I'm still a noob. Should I import the eyes into Blender as vector image plains? I made them as mesh circles. I tried opening and attaching nodes as they are in your image and there's no Vector anything. Could you please be more detailed as what to do? Step by step? When you say " Edit the white circle material so your pupil is part of the material" do you mean join the mesh as one object? Sorry for being an idiot

Sure ! Here is the file in the meantime https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6n7DpQ6sd1s673ga2nknTzGeTDTOQOi/view?usp=sharing

The pupil is no longer a mesh, it is like a texture but made with nodes instead of pixels. It is simply a different color in your eye circle mesh. The empty is then used to tell the material where to place the pupil.
For the vector nodes, I guess you had trouble finding them because they are subtypes of the "Vector Math" node. Add a vector math node and select the subtype with the dropdown

@ Romain Guimbal Hi. Thanks again  for putting all that work in to help me. Very nice of you. I hadn't been able to get back to blender because my life got in the way. I still don’t know enough to understand how you did what you did but by copying your nodes etc. I was able to make an eye how I wanted. It worked! Thanks. You’re very kind. (o:

your welcome :) have a good day

@ Romain Guimbal Hi. If you're not busy could you please help me? With my eyes, how do I add a highlight to the pupil that behaves in the same way as the pupil? There's no toolbar or anything to upload an image. Drag and drop doesn't work. Sorry. Thanks if you can help.
